# Four aces are turned down on a table and two aces are drawn out after the other. What is the probability that the ace of hearts is drawn second?

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on this one problem.  It says the probability is suppose to be 1/36.  Can you please go step by step how to get to this solution?

Comment: The probability that the ace of hearts is drawn second is $1/4$.   No wonder you are stuck.

Comment: Are you sure you are stating the problem accurately?  As I understand it, you put the four aces face down on a table, and you are asking for the probability that the Ace of Hearts is the second one.  That probability is $\frac 14$.

Comment: What do you mean by "drawn out after the other" ? Does this mean two of the aces are already drawn and neither of them was the ace of hearts?

Comment: Yes I'm stating this question correctly.  The answer was in the back of the textbook.  I believe it's asking after drawing the first card what's the probability that the second card will be an Ace of Hearts.

Comment: Can you write out the problem exactly as it appears? As it stands, the answer really appears to be $\frac 14$.  I can't even think of a variant with the answer you want.

Comment: "Four aces are turned down on a table and two aces are drawn out ONE after the other.  What is the probability that the ace of hearts is drawn second?" I forgot to add the "one after the other."

Comment: Ok...well, that's $\frac 14$.  The $A\heartsuit$ has to be in one of the four positions...there's nothing to break the symmetry, so it has an equal chance of being in any of the four slots.  Hence $\frac 14$.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is being worded wrong.  I believe it's asking for the probability that ace of cards will be drawn second without putting back the first card on two separate events.  Will rewording it that way make a difference? Thank you for answering.

Comment: I assumed that there was no replacement.  I am also assuming that we're talking about an ordinary deck, with one Ace of each suit.  To be precise:  I am assuming that the four Aces are placed in slots $A,B,C,D$.  You turn over the Ace in slot $A$ and get something other than $\heartsuit$.  You turn over the Ace in slot $B$ and find the $\heartsuit$.